# “different” or "various" at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct to start a sentence with the word "different"? for example:

> **Different** table structures are listed below.

or should it be:

> **Various** table structures are listed below.

Does it make any difference?

More context:

- I would like to point out and describe similarities and differences among several tables
- there are more than 2 tables I would like to compare
- I am going to compare only the tables included in the list (no other tables were presented before)
- tables have some common features but of course are not the same

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Why do you think sentences can start with some adjectives and not others? Did you, for example, search for sentences that begin with *different* on the web? Knowing this background will help us make a more informative answer.

Comment: @choster , I did some research, I read the following topic but I still have some doubts which word is better in my case http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/various-different

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of American English, your first sentence sounds perfectly normal to me, as does the second. I can't think of why, grammatically, there would be any difference.

As a matter of personal opinion, the use **Various** seems to imply that there will be more than two (I don't know why it sounds that way, but it rings as true as saying "few"), where with **Different** I can see there being only two tables.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both **different** and **various** can be used interchangeably and mean that *somethings* are not the same.

However, **various** only says there is variety, whereas **different** draws attention to how there is variety.

For example, if one says

> There are **various** cultures in the world.

A followup question might be

> How are they **different**?

However, if one says

> There are **different** cultures in the world.

One would not ask

> How are they **various**?

but rather

> What are the **differences**?

There needs to be at least two *somethings* for there to be a **difference**, but more than two for them to be **various** *somethings*.